# What cause of action "D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator"

Tags: android

I have infinity loop of debug messages. What cause of this message? What library uses this log? I'm confused.

```
D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
```